# Adding a "quote" button to jwysiwyg

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jwysiwyg

I'm trying to add a "quote" button to jwysiwyg, but I'm having a problem... My code for the button is like:

```
quote: {
  visible: true,
  tags: ['blockquote'],
  command: "FormatBlock",
  "arguments": ($.browser.msie || $.browser.safari) ? "<blockquote>" : "blockquote",
}
```

and it works (at least in Firefox), but when I press the button and the blockquote appears, I can't find a way to move the cursor *outside* that block, and everything I type afterwards ends up as quoted.
What could I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jwysiwyg source code has an example of how to do this:

https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg/blob/master/_help/examples/10-custom-controls.html#L23

Comment: Sadly the example just wraps/unwraps che current paragraph in blockquotes, but does nothing about "breaking out" of the quote :/